# How to use SSIS Foreach Loop to write to certain tables based on variable

Tags: loops, variables, foreach, ssis

I'm fairly new to SSIS but understand some basic concepts and have built several packages to do various tasks.

I have a base table that we will call "Base" (dbo.Base) that has information in it.  I also have 2 additional tables called Base2 and Base3.  I want to create a variable that tells SSIS to use either the data in Base2 or Base3 and then have the data in whichever table is named in the variable to copy or write to the original Base table that other processes will utilize.  Then down the road I would just need to update the variable and when I run the rest of the processes it will always use the Base table but the Base table will change based on the variable.

Ideally it would be nice to have a parameter type setup where when the first process (of about 15 in the main container) is ran it actually would ask the user which variable (Base2 or Base3) table they wanted to use.

Not sure if that makes sense or if possible but figured I would ask.

Thanks, Jay

Comment: Not sure if my understanding is correct, but you want SSIS package paused and show a prompt window to end user? Then probably it is much easier to create an app to do loop and insert tasks?

Comment: Do all the tables have the same schema? I suggest you first get this working using parameters and forget about user interaction for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Hi what you could do is have the variable in your package reference an environment variable, which you could prompt the user through a custom cmd app to set the environment variable to either base1 or base2 depending on your input, you can reference this app through an execute process task. The main issue with this is that if you want to deploy the app to SSISDB the CMD window will not pop up so if you are not looking at deploying the project it will still work.

If that is too much effort you can still use the environment variable and just change it manually when you want to switch between tables.